# How to assign a Column Heading/name to this query in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my simple query.

```
Declare @custName INT 
Set @custName = 2 
Select  case @custName 
when 1 then 'abc' 
when 2 then 'xyz'
when 3 then 'pqr'
end
```

The above query runs fine.

Output is

[image: SQL Statement]

I am thinking to assign the column or header name as Customer Name.

I tried with some permutation of the query.

- `Declare @custName INT  Set @custName = 2  Select  case @custName  as CustomerName
  when 1 then 'abc' when 2 then 'xyz'
  when 3 then 'pqr' end`
- `Declare @custName INT  Set @custName = 2  Select  CustomerName as case @custName  when 1 then 'abc' when 2 then 'xyz'
  when 3 then 'pqr' end`

But returning error.

> So my question is how to assign some appropriate header/column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways to do this in `SQL Server`:

```
<expression> as <alias>
<expression> <alias>
<alias> = <expression>
```

So for your example it can be:

```
DECLARE @custName INT  
SET @custName = 2  
SELECT  CASE @custName
          WHEN 1 THEN 'abc'
          WHEN 2 THEN 'xyz'
          WHEN 3 THEN 'pqr'
        END AS CustomerName
```

or:

```
DECLARE @custName INT  
SET @custName = 2  
SELECT  CASE @custName
          WHEN 1 THEN 'abc'
          WHEN 2 THEN 'xyz'
          WHEN 3 THEN 'pqr'
        END CustomerName
```

or:

```
DECLARE @custName INT  
SET @custName = 2  
SELECT  CustomerName = CASE @custName
          WHEN 1 THEN 'abc'
          WHEN 2 THEN 'xyz'
          WHEN 3 THEN 'pqr'
        END
```

Comment: Thanks :) .This way is posted by @Abdul, it would be great if you post the other 2 ways as well.

Comment: Yeah.Great.(Y) :)

Answer (score 2):

you can assign an alias to the result column

```
Declare @custName INT 

Set @custName = 2 

Select  case @custName 
 when 1 then 'abc' 
 when 2 then 'xyz'
 when 3 then 'pqr'
end as custname
```

Comment: Oh!! this permutation was missed :). Thanks.

Comment: one more point to check with you. Suppose I want when I run this query, sql server should prompt me to pass the @custname value

Comment: You can't. You must need to set the value to the variable ie Set @custName = 2 . Or you can create a stored procedure. SQL Server Management Studio will prompt for parameters for a stored procedure, if you right click the Stored Procedureand select "Execute Stored Procedure". Otherwise, no, it will not prompt for parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Alias Name` and use square bracket to escape the space in alias name. Between there is simple way to do this in `SQL SERVER 2012` using `Choose`

```
Declare @custName INT 

Set @custName = 2 

Select  Choose(@custName,'abc', 'xyz', 'pqr') as [Customer Name]
```